# Addition of items in a list is not woking

Tags: python, list

I first made to program to randomly generate some numbers. For this is did this

```
mylist = list()
for i in range(10):

    point1 = time.time()

    point2 = time.time()

    point3 = time.time()

    random_number = str((point1 + point2 - point3) * point1)
    result = random_number[9:13]

    print(result)
    mylist.append(result)
```

I wanted to test how statistically similar these numbers will be to numbers generated by actual pueudorandom generators. So i tried creating different functions that calculates mean and stuff. Everything works fine apart from my `sum` function, which is shown below:

```
def sum():

    length = len(mylist)
    length_later = length - 2

    def add():
        added = mylist[0] + mylist[1]
        for k in range(length_later):
           added = mylist[k + 2] + added
        return added

    result = add()
    print(result)

sum()
```

The `sum` function works completely fine on its own, when i pass test data to the list manually. However, weirdly when i try appending the data to list, the add function returns a huge 20 or something digit number.
What is happening here ? Also thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Insert useful output statements to trace the control and data flow. Remove inapplicable code; reduce working code to a hard-coded result. As the posting guidelines say, "make it easy for others to help you."

Comment: Most of all, practice some basic debugging techniques.  You posted another question with no apparent debugging effort.  This is not good for your own skills; it also leaves questions on SO that won't help anyone else.

Comment: If nothing else, put in a couple of tracing `print` statements to trace the variable values; this will show you a lot of your errors.  Also learn to test code as soon as you write it; trying to write an entire function without testing any of it is a good way to get confused.
I speak from long tears of experience in these matters ... I've made these mistakes more times than I can recall.

Comment: Sorry, i will keep that in mind from next time.

Comment: Also, look up how to validate a RNG, so you know what you'll need for "mean and stuff".  For instance, learn how to calculate a chi-squared test on your "random" sequences.

Comment: there is standard function `sum()` and you don't have to write own function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list contains strings, rather than numbers, so your `sum` function concatenates them instead of adding them numerically. Try this:

```py
    random_number = str((point1 + point2 - point3) * point1)
    result = int(random_number[9:13])
```